# Counting occurrences of a string in an array and then removing duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, twitter

I am fairly new to C# programming and I am stuck on my little ASP.NET project.

My website currently examines Twitter statuses for URLs and then adds those URLs to an array, all via a regular expression pattern matching procedure. Clearly more than one person will update a with a specific URL so I do not want to list duplicates, and I want to count the number of times a particular URL is mentioned in, say, 100 tweets.

Now I have a `List<String>` which I can sort so that all duplicate URLs are next to each other. I was under the impression that I could compare `list[i]` with `list[i+1]` and if they match, for a counter to be added to (count++), and if they don't match, then for the URL and the count value to be added to a new array, assuming that this is the end of the duplicates.

This would remove duplicates and give me a count of the number of occurrences for each URL. At the moment, what I have is not working, and I do not know why (like I say, I am not very experienced with it all).

With the code below, assume that a JSON feed has been searched for using a keyword into `srchResponse.results`. The results with URLs in them get added to `sList`, a string List type, which contains only the URLs, not the message as a whole.

I want to put one of each URL (no duplicates),  a count integer (to string) for the number of occurrences of a URL, and the username, message, and user image URL all into my jagged array called 'urls[100][]'. I have made the array 100 rows long to make sure everything can fit but generally, this is too big. Each 'row' will have 5 elements in them.

The debugger gets stuck on the line:  `if (sList[i] == sList[i + 1])` which is the crux of my idea, so clearly the logic is not working. Any suggestions or anything will be seriously appreciated!

Here is sample code:

```
  var sList = new ArrayList();

    string[][] urls = new string[100][];

    int ctr = 0;
    int j = 1;

    foreach (Result res in srchResponse.results)
    {           

        string content = res.text;
        string pattern = @"((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|notes|ms-help):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, pattern);

      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {

        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;

                    sList.Add(groups[0].Value.ToString());
      }
    }

    sList.Sort();    
    foreach (Result res in srchResponse.results)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (sList[i] == sList[i + 1])
            {
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                urls[ctr][0] = sList[i].ToString();
                urls[ctr][1] = j.ToString();
                urls[ctr][2] = res.text;
                urls[ctr][3] = res.from_user;
                urls[ctr][4] = res.profile_image_url;
                ctr++;
                j = 1;
            }
        }



    }
```

The code then goes on to add each result into a StringBuilder method with the HTML.

Is now edite

Comment: Are you able to utilize LINQ (i.e. can you use the 3.0 version of the framework)? It can do exactly what you're asking in about 1 line of code :)

Comment: I am using 3.5 framework... Can you give me an example of implementing LINQ or where I can find out more??

Comment: Nice examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx - More specific to this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1

Comment: Your third paragraph makes no sense, syntactically.

Comment: Yes sorry I am muddling arrays and lists... I am using a List to compare and putting it into an Array... Arrays and Lists are fairly interchangeable... i wish Arrays had the methods (and power) of Lists!

Message updated!

Comment: I don't understand the Twitter aspect so I have one question before I suggest a solution: Your final logic appears to account for only one 'res' per URL (since 'urls[][]' is intended to be a unique array of URLs). In the Twitter response can more than one 'res' be associated with an single URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The description of your algorithm seems fine. I don't know what's wrong with the implementation; I haven't read it that carefully. (The fact that you are using an ArrayList is an immediate red flag; why aren't you using a more strongly typed generic collection?)

However, I have a suggestion. This is exactly the sort of problem that LINQ was intended to solve.  Instead of writing all that error-prone code yourself, just **describe the transformation you're interested in**, and let the *compiler* work it out for you.

Suppose you have a list of strings and you wish to determine the number of occurrences of each:

```
var notes = new []{ "Do", "Fa", "La", "So", "Mi", "Do", "Re" };

var counts = from note in notes 
             group note by note into g
             select new { Note = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }

foreach(var count in counts)
    Console.WriteLine("Note {0} occurs {1} times.", count.Note, count.Count);
```

Which I hope you agree is much easier to read than all that array logic you wrote.  And of course, now you have your sequence of unique items; you have a sequence of counts, and each count contains a unique Note.

Comment: Very interesting and helpful... LINQ I realise now is my way out of this problem. What would be a more strongly typed generic collection? You mean a collection I define myself (a collection  of objects that uses internal properties for comparison?)

Again thanks Eric, nice stuff.

Comment: Looks like I  missed the notification of other answers being posted. I'll delete mine in lieu of this response...

Comment: @AlexW - In this case `List<string>` would be the strongly typed generic collection you need because the list of URLs will explicitly contain strings and only strings (there's obviously more to generics than this, but this is a simple explanation). `ArrayList.Add()` takes `object` types, which could be anything that inherits from `object` (which happens to be everything in .NET)!. Good tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jgodel/Page102062006170216PM/Page1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a more sophisticated data structure than an array.  A Set will guarantee that you have no duplicates.

Looks like C# collections doesn't include a Set, but there are 3rd party implementations available, like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/collections/SetCollectionsForCSharp.aspx).

Comment: @duffymo - there is a set structure and it's called `HashSet<>` and it was introduced in .NET 3.5. They couldn't call it Set because that could conflict with the `Set` keyword in Visual Basic.

Comment: Thank you, John.  Couldn't a namespace have sorted that issue out?  I thought that was what it was for.  Is there a TreeSet or any other implementation as well?

Comment: @duffymo - In VB `Set` is a keyword (just like `for` or `if`) so a namespace change wouldn't help. I believe at this point there are no other implementations since there is no interface for a set, but the structure itself isn't sealed so there could be more. Looks as though in .NET 4.0 they're creating an `ISet<>` interface which will allow for other implementations though.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop fails because when i == 99, (i + 1) == 100 which is outside the bounds of your array.

But as other have pointed out, .Net 3.5 has ways of doing what you want more elegantly.

Comment: I did try using lower values actually, e.g. i < 40 and it still didn't work!

Comment: What happens then is that it says  urls[ctr][1] = j.ToString(); has an error: Null Reference Exception...???

I am still confused! I'll try using LINQ and re-writing the whole thing

Comment: Maybe if I override the ToString method, this will work for my integer j = 1;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know how many duplicates a specific entry has you could do the following:

LINQ Extension Methods

```
.Count()   
.Distinct()  
.Count()
```